# How to skip invalid rows when reading data frame from file in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large file which contains lots of data, and I'd like to read it into dataframe, but found some invalid rows. These invalid rows cause the read.table to break. I try the following method to skip invalid lines, but it seems the performance is very bad.

```
counts<-count.fields(textConnection(lines),sep="\001")
raw_data<-read.table(textConnection(lines[counts == 34]), sep="\001")
```

Is there any better way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: What is bad in your definition?

Comment: Any reason you're not using `read.table` directly? It has a lot of arguments to select and ignore various "bad" characters. There's also an argument to "fill" incomplete rows, if that is the problem you're having.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

using @PaulHiemstra's sample data:

```
read.table("test.csv", sep = ";", fill=TRUE)
```

then you take care of the NAs as you wish.

Comment: I added your answer as an additional option to the benchmarks

Comment: Lazy me-- this was my answer in my first comment, but you wrote it out in much better detail

Comment: @Carl, +1 for your comment karma.

Comment: It would be even better to combine this with `na.string=""`, this way all blank cells with be recognized as NA.

Answer (score 5):

What you could do is iterate over the lines in the file, and only add the lines that have the correct length.

I defined the following test csv file:

```
1;2;3;4
1;2;3;4
1;2;3
1;2;3;4
```

Using `read.table` fails:

```
> read.table("test.csv", sep = ";")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :                                                                       
  line 3 did not have 4 elements
```

Now an iterative approach:

```
require(plyr)
no_lines = 4
correct_length = 4
file_con = file("test.csv", "r")
result = ldply(1:no_lines, function(line) {
   dum = strsplit(readLines(file_con, n = 1), split = ";")[[1]]
   if(length(dum) == correct_length) {
     return(dum)
   } else {
     cat(sprintf("Skipped line %s\n", line))
     return(NULL)
   }
  })
close(file_con)

> result
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  2  3  4
3  1  2  3  4
```

Ofcourse this is a trivial example as the file is really small. Let us create a more challenging example to act as a benchmark.

```
# First file with invalid rows
norow = 10e5    # number of rows
no_lines = round(runif(norow, min = 3, max = 4))
no_lines[1] = correct_length
file_content = ldply(no_lines, function(line) paste(1:line, collapse = ";"))
writeLines(paste(file_content[[1]], sep = "\n"), "big_test.csv")

# Same length with valid rows
file_content = ldply(rep(4, norow), function(line) paste(1:line, collapse = ";"))
writeLines(paste(file_content[[1]], sep = "\n"), "big_normal.csv")
```

Now for the benchmark

```
# Iterative approach
system.time({file_con <- file("big_test.csv", "r")
    result_test <- ldply(1:norow, function(line) {
       dum = strsplit(readLines(file_con, n = 1), split = ";")[[1]]
       if(length(dum) == correct_length) {
         return(dum)
       } else {
         # Commenting this speeds up by 30%
         #cat(sprintf("Skipped line %s\n", line))
         return(NULL)
       }
      })
    close(file_con)})
   user  system elapsed 
 20.559   0.047  20.775

# Normal read.table
system.time(result_normal <- read.table("big_normal.csv", sep = ";"))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.060   0.015   1.079 

# read.table with fill = TRUE
system.time({result_fill <- read.table("big_test.csv", sep = ";", fill=TRUE)
             na_rows <- complete.cases(result_fill)
             result_fill <- result_fill[-na_rows,]})
   user  system elapsed 
  1.161   0.033   1.203 

# Specifying which type the columns are (e.g. character or numeric)
# using the colClasses argument.
system.time({result_fill <- read.table("big_test.csv", sep = ";", fill=TRUE, 
                                       colClasses = rep("numeric", 4))
             na_rows <- complete.cases(result_fill)
             result_fill <- result_fill[-na_rows,]})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.933   0.064   1.001
```

So the iterative approach is quite a bit slower, but 20 seconds for 1 million rows might be acceptable (although this depends on your definition of acceptable). Especially when you only have to this once, and than save it using `save` for later retrieval. The solution suggested by @Paolo is almost as fast as the normal call to `read.table`. Rows that contain the wrong amount of columns (thus `NA`'s) are eliminated using `complete.cases`. Specifying which classes the columns are further improves the performance, and I think this effect is going to be bigger when the amount of columns and rows gets bigger.

So in conclusion, the best option is to use `read.table` with `fill = TRUE`, while specifying the classes of the columns. The iterative approach using `ldply` is only a good option if you want more flexibility in the choice of how to read the lines, e.g. only read the line if a certain value is above a threshold. But probably this could be done quicker by reading all the data into R, and than creating a subset. Only when the data is bigger than your RAM, I could imagine the iterative approach having its merits.